# How to get on screen rows from List in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

I'm trying to put a `Text` for each visible (within the screen bounds) row in a List of their current index in all the visible rows.

I have an example here. If I have a list showing 3 rows at a time, and initially I want it showing like this:

```
___|___
A  |  0
B  |  1
C  |  2
-------
```

And if I scroll the list down, and A goes out of the screen, then it will be like

```
___|___
B  |  0
C  |  1
D  |  2
-------
```

Any idea how can I do it?

Besides, I used to use [UITableView.visibleCells](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614896-visiblecells) to obtain the visible cells on screen, but I couldn't find something similar in SwiftUI. How exactly am I suppose to get visible row in a list with only index provided in SwiftUI?

Hope someone can direct me to the right place. Thanks a lot!

Comment: what is `0`, `1`, or `2` in this context?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use [onAppear](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/text/3276931-onappear) and [onDisappear](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/text/3276933-ondisappear) functions to maintain a list of visible rows and then use these to find a visible index.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    let rows = (Unicode.Scalar("A").value...Unicode.Scalar("Z").value)
        .map { String(Unicode.Scalar($0)!) }

    @State var visibleRows: Set<String> = []

    var body: some View {
        List(rows, id: \.self) { row in
            HStack {
                Text(row)
                    .padding(40)
                    .onAppear { self.visibleRows.insert(row) }
                    .onDisappear { self.visibleRows.remove(row) }
            }
            Spacer()
            Text(self.getVisibleIndex(for: row)?.description ?? "")
        }
    }

    func getVisibleIndex(for row: String) -> Int? {
        visibleRows.sorted().firstIndex(of: row)
    }
}
```

Comment: that's really great!

Comment: Didn’t thought about this! Thanks a lot

Comment: The problem is that if the system does any caching, it won't fire `onAppear`. So you view item 1 and then item 2 and `onAppear` fires, go back to item1 and `onAppear` does not fire again.

Comment: Another thing to note is that a cell is still technically visible when it is behind a navigation bar. So you may not "see" the cell, but it will still be in your list of `visibleRows`.

Answer (score 0):

While you could use `.onAppear` and `.onDisappear`, those modifiers are based on SwiftUI's conception of appearance, rather than user visibility. It's common for a view, for example, to be out of sight for the user but still visible to SwiftUI until a *new* `List` item is loaded.

To appropriately measure which `List` items are visible to the user, you'll need the items to report their positions, then filter the ones based on some condition that determines visibility. In practice, that means using [preferences](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/preferences) to send information *up* the view hierarchy.

The best way to accomplish that is with anchor preferences ([Swift with Majid has a very good article on this](https://swiftwithmajid.com/2020/03/18/anchor-preferences-in-swiftui/)). If you're using a `ScrollView`, you may be able to get away with [`scrollPosition(id:anchor:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/scrollposition(id:anchor:)); but preferences allow you to specify your own filtering criteria.

First, you'll need the preference:

```swift
struct VisibleItem<Item> {
  let item: Item
  let anchor: Anchor<CGRect>
}

struct VisiblePreferenceKey<Item>: PreferenceKey {
  typealias Value = [VisibleItem<Item>]

  static var defaultValue: Value { [] }

  static func reduce(value: inout Value, nextValue: () -> Value) {
    value.append(contentsOf: nextValue())
  }
}
```

`VisibleItem` will be the struct useful for filtering via visibility. The reason it has an `Anchor` is because it allows you to convert the geometry of a view into the coordinate space of another (in other words, it allows the filtering to actually encompass the user visible space)

The preference will then be applied to `List` items that should report their positions:

```swift
struct UserImages: View {
  let images: [UserImage]

  var body: some View {
    List(images) { image in
      UserImageView(image: image)
        .anchorPreference(key: VisiblePreferenceKey.self, value: .bounds) { [.init(item: image, anchor: $0)] }
    }
  }
}
```

Note that we're storing `image` as the item so we can reference it after we filter.

Finally, on your `List`, you can read the preference value and apply your filtering:

```swift
struct UserImages: View {
  let images: [UserImage]

  var body: some View {
    List(images) { image in
      // ...
    }.backgroundPreferenceValue(VisiblePreferenceKey<UserImage>.self) { items in
      GeometryReader { proxy in
        let local = proxy.frame(in: .local)
        let images = items
          .filter { local.intersects(proxy[$0.anchor]) }
          .map(\.item)

        // Do something with `images`
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm using [`backgroundPreferenceValue(_:_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/backgroundpreferencevalue(_:_:)) here just to demonstrate, but as can be seen, the frame of the `List` is stored in `local`, and each item is filtered with respect to the `List`'s coordinate space (the `proxy[$0.anchor]`), and checked to see if the two `CGRect`s intersect (in other words, do they overlap?)

You could do a lot with this, but **for your specific case**, what you could do is use a `Color.clear.onChange(of: images) {...}` and store the order of each item in your model so you can display it in your UI (items is already sorted by the preference key). If you wanted to be more strict, per say, and only include items that are completely visible (so a view that is half-scrolled out is not counted), you could e.g. change `local.intersects(...)` to `local.contains(...)`.

Comment: Won't the array inside the preference key get bigger? Isn't it better to use dict instead?

Comment: @Hohenheim the array will grow to be as large as the number of images. If there were 5 images, then 10, and now 8, the array will have a size of 5, 10, and 8, respectively. A dictionary is not inherently more efficient, as in the example all images are being used.

Comment: does LazyVStack also behaves the same? This is how I understand it, please correct me. Everytime list-item anchor changes(like origin, size), reduce function is called and appends a new instance of `VisibleItem` to the list.

Comment: The preference starts with an empty array (as per `defaultValue`) and grows with each call to `reduce`. I think you're confused as to when `reduce` is called, which is when a view that is on-screen has one of the preference modifiers applied (here, `UserImageView` with `anchorPreference`). `List` only displays views on-screen, and so does `LazyVStack` (i.e. they're similar). So if you have, say, 100 images, and only 5 are displayed, but only 2 are visible to the user (the other three are out-of-view but still on-screen), the array will have 5 items at that moment in time.

Comment: Sorry this might be dumb question but, why does it only have 5 items, we always append and never reassign a new array and reduce function is called multiple times.

Comment: It's because SwiftUI uses `defaultValue` to create the array, `reduce` to build it, and discarded in a loop. SwiftUI is not keeping a single copy of `defaultValue` and always calling `reduce` with it; it's keeping it for the views *in that point of time*. With anchor preferences, it's very frequent. This is why the example only has 5 elements—only 5 views are on-screen, so it'll only have 5 items at that point in time. Later, it may have 3, or 6.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use the onAppear modifier with LazyHStack or LazyVStack's subview. Place this LazyHStack or LazyVStack inside the ScrollView.
e.g.

Here is the scroll view and LazyVStack

```
import SwiftUI

struct ProductListView: View {
    var staff = [
        Person(name: "Ram", phoneNumber: "(408) 555-4301"),
        Person(name: "Aman", phoneNumber: "(919) 555-2481"),
        Person(name: "John", phoneNumber: "(408) 555-4301"),
        Person(name: "Jeff", phoneNumber: "(408) 555-4301"),
        Person(name: "Boing", phoneNumber: "(408) 555-4301"),
        Person(name: "Kim", phoneNumber: "(408) 555-4301"),
        Person(name: "Juhi", phoneNumber: "(408) 555-4301"),
        Person(name: "Mei Chen", phoneNumber: "(919) 555-2481"),
        Person(name: "Rahul", phoneNumber: "(408) 555-4301"),
        Person(name: "Mahesh", phoneNumber: "(408) 555-4301"),
        Person(name: "Ninja", phoneNumber: "(408) 555-4301"),
        Person(name: "Rohit", phoneNumber: "(408) 555-4301")
    ]
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.vertical) {
            LazyVStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 10) {
                ForEach(staff) { person in
                    ProductListItem.init(title: person.name, description: person.phoneNumber)
                        .onAppear(perform: {
                            print("Item appred - ", person.name)
                        })
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the List Item

```
import SwiftUI

struct ProductListItem: View {
    let title: String
    let description: String
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .bottom, content: {
            Image("placeholder", bundle: nil)
                .resizable()
            HStack(alignment: .bottom, content: {
                VStack(alignment: .leading, content: {
                    Text(title).font(.headline)
                        .foregroundStyle(.white)
                    Text(description).font(.subheadline)
                        .foregroundStyle(.white)
                })
                Spacer()
            })
            .padding()
            .foregroundColor(.primary)
            .background(Color.secondary
                .colorInvert()
                .opacity(0.90))
        })
    }
}
```

NOTE - Just to increase the item size add some placeholder image in assets folder.